# Find permissions of service account associated with buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have created a service account using the command

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create test-sa --display-name "TEST SA"
```

And then I go ahead and give this service account admin privileges on a GCS bucket.

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:test-sa@<PROJECT>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:admin gs://<BUCKET>
```

Now I want a method to check what roles/permissions are granted to a service account.

One way is to do something like:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT>  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format='table(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members: serviceAccount:test-sa@<PROJECT>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

But the above command returns empty.

But if I get the ACL for the bucket, I can clearly see that the members and the roles for the bucket.

```
gsutil iam get gs://<BUCKET>
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:test-sa@<PROJECT>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.admin"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:<PROJECT>",
        "projectOwner:<PROJECT>"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:<PROJECT>"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "CAI="
}
```

Can someone guide me as to how can I view the buckets/permissions associated with a service account and not the other way around ?

Comment: none of the answers clarified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are mixing project-level roles with bucket-level roles by assigning the permissions to the bucket directly(bucket-level role), and then checking at project-level. You can find more information about this [over here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#project-level_roles_vs_bucket-level_roles).

This is why you get different results when checking either the project(cloud projects get-iam-policy ) or the bucket(gsutil iam get gs://).

You should stick to using either bucket-level roles or project-level roles and avoid mixing the 2 as if you start mixing them, it is gonna get tricky to know what roles each user has and were.

Depending on the number of buckets you plan to manage, it may be easier for you to stick to bucket-level roles and just iterate over a list of buckets when checking the permissions of a user as you can do this very easily with the Cloud SDK in a little for cycle such as:

```
for i in $(cat bucket-list.txt)
do
    gsutil iam get gs://$i
done
```

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

As you are giving permission at Bucket ACL level and not using service account iam-binding, 
`gcloud projects get-iam-policy` command wont return this permission.
You can only get this from querying bucket ACL.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign permission at a resource such as a Project/Folder/Organization and at individual resources such as buckets, objects, compute engine instances, KMS keys, etc. There is no single command that checks everything.

At the Project level permissions are project-wide. At the resource level such as an object, only affect that object. You will need to check everything to know exactly what/where an IAM member has permissions.